# vb.net combobox data changes

Tags: vb.net, .net-3.5, combobox

I am making my final year VB.NET project, I am using Visual Studio 2008 with 3.5 framework

I am making a Restaurant Bill generation software.

I have created the table in SQL and connected to the project, I added 6 combo boxes with drop down,

I have assigned drop-downs as the Menu item of the restaurant, when I run the program and try to change one combo box item, all combo box items get changed. How can I avoid this?

How to get rid of this?

I am not a professional in this, but any help will be appreciated

Comment: @Elad Lachmi I didn't get you, what I have to do? To check what you said

Comment: @Elad Lachmi I didn't code anything to put data into combobox, I used the GUI, on combo box I clicked on the icon to add database, and followed the steps, and the data is also added.
Did I do something wrong?

Comment: @Dvd Prd  ASP? but I am not working in it? I am fully into VB.net

Comment: I`m sorry. I was thinking you were working on a ASP.NET web application. Sorry.

Comment: So you pick an item on one combobox and other comboboxes change as well?

Comment: @Dvd Prd yes other combo box value gets change, and all other combo box has the same table of database, But I don't that if I change one combo box value then the others should also change

Comment: @Elad Lachmi its OK, but how do I solve this in VB.NET?

Comment: Can you please post the code for the OnSelectedIndexChanged method of the combobox that changes the other comboboxes?

Comment: @Elad Lachmi I haven't written any code in that event, cause I inserted data into combo box through GUI

Comment: So the method was generated automatically. Nothing happens by magic :) We still need to see it in order to help.

Comment: @Elad Lachmi I ll tell you the steps, which I followed,
First I added the database into Data sources by following the wizard(no coding in this), I inserted successfully and it worked, then on form, I dragged a combo box, on the icon to select the database on combo box(named as COMBO BOX TASKS), I clicked and inserted the appropriate table into it, thats it, I followed these steps for my other combo boxes.

Comment: Did you insert different tables in to the different comboboxes? Do these tables have foreign keys?

Comment: @Elad Lachmi No I didn't insert different tables in different boxes, all boxes are having same table of same data base, And the tables have no foreign keys

Comment: Then show us a screenshot. Give us something to work with. I am really trying to help you.

Comment: @Elad Lachmi Hey I solved this, I really appreciate your help, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess that you've bound them all to exactly the same BindingSource (which is pointing at the same data), in which case changing the selection in one combobox will immediately be reflected in the others. If you have multiple items bound to the same BindingSource (which is what the wizard will give you if you're not careful), and don't want a change in one to reflect in the others, you need to create separate BindingSources for each one.

Comment: OK, how to create different binding source, I mean normally till now, I have followed the GUI method and was successfull, but how to add more datBinding?